# How to catch SPI panic (LoadProhibited) crashes? ESP32, SPI, SD, TFT

Tags: debugging, arduino, try-catch, esp32, spi

I need a technique to debug an SPI crash I regularly get.

I'm getting a Panic, LoadProhibited crash in an ESP32 design. I have MJPEG files stored on a NAND/SD card and a 240x240 pixel TFT display. Both are connected to the VSPI. I use GPIO32 for the display and GPIO 4 for the SD. They are tied to the VSPI, GPIO 23 MOSI, GPIO 19 MISO, and GPIO 18 SCK.

I start the TFT on the SPI bus with:

```cpp
Arduino_DataBus *bus = new Arduino_ESP32SPI(SPI_DisplayDC /* DC */, SPI_DisplayCS /* CS */, SPI_SCK /* SCK */, SPI_MOSI /* MOSI */, SPI_MISO /* MISO */, VSPI /* spi_num */);

Arduino_GFX *gfx = new Arduino_GC9A01(bus, SPI_DisplayRST, 2 /* rotation */, false /* IPS */);
```

then I start the SPI:

```cpp
SPI.begin(SPI_SCK, SPI_MISO, SPI_MOSI);
SPI.setFrequency(4000000);  // at 8000000 I get CPU panic reboots
```

and start the SD with:

```cpp
if ( ! SD.begin(SD_CS) )
```

I coded an MJPEG decoder that reads data from the SD and sends it to the TFT display. After about 10 seconds of normal play I get this crash:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d222d  PS      : 0x00060130  A0      : 0x800d1e60  A1      : 0x3ffb1f20  
A2      : 0x00000001  A3      : 0x3ffc1878  A4      : 0x00000000  A5      : 0x3ffc5d78  
A6      : 0x3ffb9560  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x800d2225  A9      : 0x0000001a  
A10     : 0x3ffb1f68  A11     : 0x3ffb9560  A12     : 0x0000001a  A13     : 0x3ffb957a  
A14     : 0x0000004c  A15     : 0x00000061  SAR     : 0x00000010  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000024  LBEG    : 0x4000c349  LEND    : 0x4000c36b  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x400d222d:0x3ffb1f20 0x400d1e5d:0x3ffb1f50 0x400e1f2c:0x3ffb1fb0 0x400896e2:0x3ffb1fd0

Rebooting...
```

I decode the Backtrace to get:

```
Decoding stack results 

0x400d222d: MjpegClass::readMjpegBuf() at /var/folders/8y/z6t4zfcs2611ddcwsm1cg1080000gn/T/arduino_build_687015/sketch/MjpegClass.cpp line 136 

0x400d1e5d: loop() at /Users/frankcohen/Documents/Arduino/13StoryRunner/13StoryRunner.ino line 178 

0x400e1f2c: loopTask(void*) at /Users/frankcohen/Documents/Arduino/hardware/espressif/esp32/cores/esp32/main.cpp line 23 

0x400896e2: vPortTaskWrapper at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/port.c line 143  
This is the offending line:

_buf_read = _input->readBytes(_read_buf + o, READ_BUFFER_SIZE - o);
```

I added debugging around line 136 of MjpegClass.cpp to see if maybe the buffer is corrupt or no longer valid. It looks fine.

I'm seeking advice on where I should look next?

The software repository is here:
https://github.com/frankcohen/ReflectionsOS/tree/main/Devices/Sox/Software/13StoryRunner

Comment: It's possible you might be able to get some insight using [JTAG](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/jtag-debugging/index.html). You'd need the JTAG pins (12, 13, 14, 15) available and would need a JTAG debugger to control the ESP32. It might be a wild goose chase or it might help you see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. If you are using the development board of esp32cam, the SPI bus and sd should use the same set of wires, so I suggest checking the schematic diagram of your development board.
Hope can help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).